# GREG 4.1.1 - customizing oracle

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I have problem customizing $GREG_HOME/repository/conf/registry.xml file for oracle database 10, I am using ojdbc14_1.0.0.jar.
After recommendations at http://wso2.org/project/registry/4.1.1/docs/installation_guide/db_oracle.html
Edit $GREG_HOME/repository/conf/registry.xml and give the following:

> oracle-db
>       
>         jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER_NAME:PORT/DB_NAME
>         USER_NAME
>         PASSWORD
>         oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>           80
>           60000
>           5

I have errors at the startup of carbon server ("function is not supported" in Russian):

> "    TID: [] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-03-29 15:41:41,843] 
>   INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} -
>   KDC server is disabled.
>   {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder}
>   TID: [] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-03-29 15:41:41,859]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} -  Initializing
>   Directory Server with working directory
>   D:\Distr\WSO2greg\WSO2GR~1.1\WSO2GR~1.1\bin..\repository\data\org.wso2.carbon.directory
>   and port 10389 {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} TID:
>   [] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-03-29 15:41:50,265] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCPathCache} -  Failed to
>   insert resource to /. Не поддерживаемая функция
>   {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCPathCache}
>   java.sql.SQLException: Не поддерживаемая функция  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:162)
>   "

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Governance Registry(4.5.0 onward) supports for different encoding types

Eg:

If you want to use Governance Registry with Russian, you should start the server with proper encoding type.

Windows : wso2server.bat -Dcarbon.registry.character.encoding=windows-1251
Liux    : sh wso2server.sh -Dcarbon.registry.character.encoding=windows-1251

More information : http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Supported+System+Properties